# Why do I need to CamelCase Html Attributes in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, camelcasing

Why do I need to camelcase these HTML properties in react:

```
<video autoPlay loop muted playsInline>
    <source src={url} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Why is it `autoPlay` and not `autoplay`?
Or is this an error in my VSCode warnings?

Comment: [Will this help from docs ?](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link, makes total sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive, so it might just not work with autoplay or playsinline.

But for this case, I think that this is just some common eslint (or some similar tool) warning, you can make sure by just passing those props in lowercase and see if it works